# how to encode and broadcast video for live event on youtube in programing

Tags: youtube-api

I want to encode and upload video to youtube corresponding with a live event but I cannot find how to do that on youtube api site same as the wirecast software. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a flash media encoder and rtmp streamer. I used ffmpeg libraries for both and worked fine.

Comment: use ffmpeg libraries to encode video from this format to another format, that's ok. But i don't know how to broadcast that video to youtube correspond with my live event